# Pandas - Some columns not working properly after groupby()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to generate a simple graph but doesn't make any sense to me after applied `groupBy()`

[image]

```
df_cumulate = df.groupby(['date','sentiment'], as_index=False).sum()

def plot_df(df, x, y, title="", xlabel='Date', ylabel='Sentiment', dpi=100):
    plt.figure(figsize=(16,5), dpi=dpi)
    plt.plot(x, y, color='tab:red')
    plt.gca().set(title=title, xlabel=xlabel, ylabel=ylabel)
    plt.savefig('sentiment_over_time.png')
    plt.show()

plot_df(df_cumulate, x=df_cumulate.index, y=df_cumulate.sentiment, title='Sentiment Over Time')
```

If I changed into `x=df_cumulate.date`, will get this. The `Sentiment` `sum()` logically must more than 1 or below than -1.

[image]

dataset: https://gist.github.com/datomnurdin/33961755b306bc67e4121052ae87cfbc

Comment: what do you expect the graph to look like?

Comment: It is better show us what your data should look like and what is your expected output after groupby

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to group by the date. Does this look like what you expected?

```
df_cumulate = df.groupby(['date'], as_index=False).sum()
display(df_cumulate)

def plot_df(df, x, y, title="", xlabel='Date', ylabel='Sentiment', dpi=100):
    plt.figure(figsize=(16,5), dpi=dpi)
    plt.plot(x, y, color='tab:red')
    plt.gca().set(title=title, xlabel=xlabel, ylabel=ylabel)
    plt.savefig('sentiment_over_time.png')
    plt.show()

plot_df(df_cumulate, x=df_cumulate.date, y=df_cumulate.sentiment, title='Sentiment Over Time')
```

[image]